# Failed to open stream on file_put_contents in PHP on CentOS 7

Tags: php, apache, centos, centos7

I know this is a common bug with many threads but I'm tired of searching and I still haven't solved it. When I try to run the function **file_put_contents** I get the following error:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/nurses/adminWriter.php on line 29
```

I've already done the most common answer, change the permissions of the *nurses* folder and the *test.txt* file to 777. That didn't work.

I'm currently on a fresh install of the latest CentOS 7 server.

I've found that if I run the php script through the console:

```
# php /var/www/html/nurses/adminWriter.php
```

It works just fine, I get the error only when running it through the browser,  but I really need to run it this way.

Best Regards!

Comment: When you run a php script through apache, it runs as (whatever user you specify), often "apache".  When you run a php script through the console, you're running it as whatever you're logged in as.  Ensure the "apache" (or whatever) user can access that file (which includes any parent directories).  Also, you may try using an absolute path to test.txt -- you may be trying to write somewhere you're not expecting.

Comment: Did you skip the quote by purpose ? Try that : `file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/test.txt');`

Comment: You mean doing something like: # chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/nurses/

Comment: Yes I'm doing: file_put_contents('teste.txt', 'this is my content'); Already tried with full path to file a with ( '/var/www/html/nurses' . 'teste.txt' )

Comment: The code from your comment is missing a forward slash: `'/var/www/html/nurses/'.'teste.txt'`

Comment: Yes, but still no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue: selinux

Here's the solution:
http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/11142

In case the page goes down:

**Symptoms**

After you change the default directory to store website content (say, to "/home"), you are unable to access the content of subdomains and additional websites over the Web.

**Cause**

This problem occurs if **SELinux** works in "**Enforcement**" mode. In this mode, webroot directories for websites and subdomains inside them have different permissions, and your web server fails to access them. Run this command:

```
# getenforce
```

The output should be: **Enforcing**

**Resolution**

Disable **SELinux** support: Open the file */etc/selinux/config* in any editor and find this row:

```
SELINUX=<value>
```

Change it to:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

If you cannot find this file, open the file /boot/grub/grub.conf in any editor and add the parameter **selinux=0** to the Grub Boot Loader:

```
title SE-Linux Test System
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.4.20-selinux-XXXXXXXXXX ro root=/dev/hda1 nousb selinux=0
#initrd /boot/initrd-2.4.20-selinux-XXXXXXXXXX.img
```

Reboot the server to apply the changes.
If you do not want to reboot, run this command:

```
# setenforce 0
```

Comment: Disabling SELinux is not recommend. There are better ways of doing it.

Comment: @Ilia Rostovtsev I ran into this same problem, and disabling SELinux fixed it, what other better ways of doing it without disabling SELinux ?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev  What are the "better ways of doing it" ??

Comment: It was years ago, and I can not remember exactly now, what I did to solve this right but I'm sure, that I applied the rules and/or changed context. Familiar to what is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501934/1455661

Comment: strange i don't know what is SELINUX & why it is not recommended to disable it but beside that this solution works like a charm in my case.

Answer (score 20):

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t /dir
```

This may help,rather than turn off the selinux.

Comment: Could you explain what this does please?

Comment: thanks `aureport -a` before run chcon  
{{{
     24. 09-10-2017 16:25:31 httpd system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 2 file read unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 denied 923
     25. 09-10-2017 16:26:42 httpd system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 2 file read unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 denied 924
     26. 09-10-2017 16:29:38 httpd system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 2 file read unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 denied 925
}}}

Comment: This one worked for me. U saved my time after working for many hours. use sudo chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t /dir