# Permission denied with move_uploaded_file();

Tags: php, upload, centos7

I get the error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/images/content/1485397694.JPG): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/content/admin.blog.edit.php on line 48

When I try to upload an image.

The /var/www/html/images folder has permission 777, but it still doesn't solve this problem. I searched for hours now but can't get any further.

```
    $newfilename = round(microtime(true)).'.'.end($temp);
if (file_exists("/var/www/html/images/content/".$newfilename)) {
  $file_exists = 1;
} else {
  if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/var/www/html/images/content/".$newfilename)) {
    $upload_failed = 1;
  }
}
```

This is the ps aux | grep httpd :

```
root       836  0.0  1.4 628300 28116 ?        Ss   04:02   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    1048  0.0  0.5 628564 10216 ?        S    04:02   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    1052  0.0  0.7 631208 14260 ?        S    04:02   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    1168  0.0  0.7 631392 14592 ?        S    04:02   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    1169  0.0  0.4 628436  9780 ?        S    04:02   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    1234  0.0  0.4 628436  9780 ?        S    04:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    1235  0.0  0.6 631360 13428 ?        S    04:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    1236  0.0  0.6 631208 13544 ?        S    04:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    1237  0.0  0.6 631180 13996 ?        S    04:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    1288  0.0  0.4 628436  9780 ?        S    04:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    1298  0.0  0.4 628300  8812 ?        S    04:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root      1303  0.0  0.0 112668   964 pts/1    R+   04:24   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd
```

Comment: which OS are you running under?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Centos 7

Comment: make sure that the group (rights) and permissions are correct and that all folders leading to it have the right permissions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the folder is set with group webadmin, owner apache and right 2777 (including GID)

Comment: do all of those folders exist? here are a few related links to Q&A's http://stackoverflow.com/q/8103860/1415724 --- http://stackoverflow.com/q/16299861/1415724 --- https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=59697 --- http://stackoverflow.com/q/28786047/1415724

Comment: and \*NIX is case-sensitive also.

Comment: Still doesn't do anything for me. Still the same error code.

Comment: `ps aux | grep httpd` ?

Comment: Added in the question @mwweb

Comment: `sudo chown root /var/www/html/images/content/` and `sudo chmod -R 0755  /var/www/html/images/content/`

Comment: @mwweb doesn't work.

Comment: `sudo chown root /var/www/html/images/` and `sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/images/`

Comment: @mwweb also does not work..

Comment: `php -i | grep 'upload_tmp_dir'`

Comment: PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in Unknown on line 0
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value

Comment: are u using filezilla?

Comment: No, Putty and WinSCP (sftp)

Comment: check permission of html folder

Comment: Also 777 and root:webadmin

Answer (score 1):

Just because your /images file might have the correct permissions doesn't necessarily mean that the /images/content file that it looks like you are moving the image to has the correct permissions. Try directly changing the folder you are moving files to, not just the parent older.

Comment: Also has 777 permission

Answer (score 0):

You're testing

```
file_exists("/var/www/html/images/content/".$newfilename)
```

and then trying to move it if the file does not exist. The error is in your conditional logic. The attempt to move,

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/var/www/html/images/content/".$newfilename)) {
    $upload_failed = 1;
}
```

should be moved to the clause where the files exists.

Comment: Okay, but still doesn't upload a file.