# PHP - fopen(file, "a") fails on Linux

Tags: php, linux, file-permissions, fopen

I have two files : 
`X.txt` with ownership `www-data : www-data` and 777 permissions. When I try to execute `fopen("X.txt","w+")` everything works just fine, while `fopen("X.txt","a")` fails and an error is raised because permission is denied.

It might be helpful to mention that before `X.txt` was owned by `www-data : www-data` it was owned by `usr:usr` and `fopen("X.txt","w+")` failed as well.

More helpful data :

-`X.txt` is located in `/var/www/reports`.

-PHP is not running under safe mode

It would be really helpful to understand what might cause this problem, ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: are both files in the same directory? who owns the directory? what's that directory and their parents permissions? Is php running on safe mode?

Comment: Edited and added information that might be helpful

Comment: And what happens with `file_get_contents('/var/www/reports/X.txt')`?

Comment: file_get_contents seems to work

Comment: don't say "under". 'owned by` would be more appropriate. in a file-system context, "under" implies a directory hierarchy, not permissions.

Comment: Probably no write permissions for the folders containing your files.

Comment: Directory write permission would only be needed if it's creating the file, not if it's writing to an existing file.

Comment: This is very strange. Opening for write and append should require the same permissions. They both require write permission on the file, or write on the directory only if the file needs to be created.

Comment: The ownership of the PHP script is totally irrelevant. When you run PHP from the webserver, it runs as `www-data`, not the owner of the script.

Comment: Perhaps it's SELinux? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501349/selinux-influences-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-php-error

Comment: Can you add the output from `ls -lZ /var/www/reports/X.txt` to the question?